# Subqueries in SQL for select

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, cursor, subquery

I want to filter records in my cursor using inner and outer select statements.
How do I achieve that?

I want only '_02' records from both tables.

```
table A:
col1
1122_01
1234_02
3456_02
7899_02

table B:
col1
1111_02
1234_02
4567_02

table Final:
col1
3456_02
7899_02


SELECT distinct a.col1
    FROM A a  
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B b
                                WHERE b.col1 = a.col1
                                 and b.col1='02')
and a.col1='02'
```

will this work?

Or this?

```
SELECT distinct t.item, t.skuloc loc 
FROM SCPOMGR.UDT_DFUTOSKUMAP t 
     , SCPOMGR.udt_gen_param G 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM SCPOMGR.SKU s1 
                       , SCPOMGR.udt_gen_param G 
                       ,SCPOMGR.UDT_DFUTOSKUMAP t 
                   WHERE s1.ITEM = t.ITEM 
                   AND s1.LOC = t.SKULOC 
                   and G.region='XYZ' 
                   and G.jda_code= substr(s1.loc,-2,2)
              )
and G.region='XYZ' 
and G.jda_code= substr(T.SKUloc,-2,2)
```

Comment: your example does not make sense to me

Comment: Cursor? I see no cursors.

Comment: @P.Salmon I am using this in a cursor

Comment: @juergend  ->   SELECT distinct t.item, t.skuloc loc FROM SCPOMGR.UDT_DFUTOSKUMAP t , SCPOMGR.udt_gen_param G WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SCPOMGR.SKU s1 , SCPOMGR.udt_gen_param G ,SCPOMGR.UDT_DFUTOSKUMAP t WHERE s1.ITEM = t.ITEM AND s1.LOC = t.SKULOC and G.region='XYZ' and G.jda_code= substr(s1.loc,-2,2)) and G.region='XYZ' and G.jda_code= substr(T.SKUloc,-2,2)

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include further information or clarifications. Comments are not suited for this purpose, and especially for code which is virtually unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the set of

- distinct values of `A.col1`
- for which the same value does not exist in `B.col1`
- ending in `_02`.

If you will work using SQL it is vitally important to learn to specify what you want very precisely. SQL is, at is heart, a scheme for specifying sets of data. Use the concepts of elementary set theory when specifying requirements to be realized with SQL.

Once you have a precise specification, writing it in SQL is usually easy. If you can't express what you want in SQL, *revisit the specification.*

In your case:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT A.col1
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B ON A.col1 = B.col1
   WHERE B.col1 IS NULL
     AND A.col1 LIKE `%_02`
```

This uses `LIKE '%suffix` for the third requirement, the old `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` trick for the second requirement, and `DISTINCT A.col1` for the first.

This particular query works in various SQL dialects. Cursors have nothing to do with this case.

Comment: SELECT distinct t.item, t.skuloc loc
    FROM SCPOMGR.UDT_DFUTOSKUMAP t  , 
    SCPOMGR.udt_gen_param G
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SCPOMGR.SKU s1 , SCPOMGR.udt_gen_param G ,SCPOMGR.UDT_DFUTOSKUMAP t
                                WHERE s1.ITEM = t.ITEM
                                AND s1.LOC = t.SKULOC 
                                and G.region='XYZ' 
                                and G.jda_code= substr(s1.loc,-2,2))
    
    and G.region='XYZ' 
    and G.jda_code= substr(T.SKUloc,-2,2)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your comment represents. But, for performance reasons I don't recommend `WHERE NOT EXISTS` in place of `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL`.

Comment: I dont wish to use a join .Can i not work with subquery here, as is the case?

Comment: the comment is the code snippet, where i want distinct item and loc from dfutoskumap, where that particular item does not exist in sku table, limiting the domain of both the tables to 'XYZ' region.

Comment: @O.Jones - performance varies across database flavours. In Oracle WHERE NOT EXISTS and LEFT JOIN ... NULL resolve to the same execution plan and the same performance profile. YMMV

Comment: @sahibathakral - why don't you wish to use a join?